# Cannot find template location

Tags: java, spring

I have created a simple application using **Spring** and everything is working, **Spring boot** up however I get this warning which prevents my page from being seen:

```
2017-01-03 14:15:19.522  WARN 4456 --- [  restartedMain].t.AbstractTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

However, I've got my templates in a folder and I do not know what is wrong. Please note I am begineer in **Spring**.

To show how my directory looks like I am uploading an image. Please tell my in any other information is required

[image]

Comment: Can't say exactly without knowing the classpath and the project structure with regards to `templates`, or seeing where `classpath:/templates/` is defined. My guess is it should be `classpath:templates/` or maybe `classpath*:templates/`, but it's guessing without the above info.

Comment: This will probobly be a dump question but how can I check classpaths?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html if you add them to src/main/resources/templates should do the trick as resources is in the classpath by default.

Comment: @Essex Boy well this is where my templates are

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Not sure, since I don't use IntelliJ, but you'd right click on the project and look in some sort of properties of project configuration to find it. You could also follow (and maybe should) Essex Boy's suggestion and put the folder in `src/main/resources`

Comment: @Christopher Schneider This is the thing I have templates folder inside src/main/resources and it still can't locate it

Comment: Okay works, my bad as resources folder was inside java folder not inside main. Thanks for help works fine now ;)

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into the same issue, not quite sure how it has happened but in my project .classpath file there was a rule that excludes all the sources under **src/main/resources**. i removed that and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
Looks like something wrong with created by IDE Run Configuration.
I've used `Gradle` and its `bootRun` task runs application properly.